# In web audio, what's the difference between using .value(x) and setValueAtTime(x, context.currentTime)?

Tags: html, audio, web-audio-api

I am modifying the delayTime audio parameter of a delayNode. I have tried using the value property directly, as in:

`delayNode.delayTime.value = x`

and also - what I thought was equivalent - the setValueAtTime method with the current time of the context:

`delayNode.delayTime.setValueAtTime(x, context.currentTime)`

Taking a look at the web audio spec [here](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-value), I read this in the `value` section of audio parameters:

> The effect of setting this (.value) attribute is equivalent to calling
>   setValueAtTime() with the current AudioContext's currentTime and the
>   requested value.

Nonetheless, I noticed that using `.value` directly causes a big audio glitch, whereas `.setValueAtTime` is much less noisy. You can hear this in these two jsFiddles by clicking in the button (it's noisy btw):

- [Change delayTime with .value](https://jsfiddle.net/wesnz83g/1/)
- [Change delayTime with .setValueAtTime](https://jsfiddle.net/vr5m0mgj/2/)

My question is: What is the difference between using the `value` attribute and using `.setValueAtTime` with the current time? Why are they different? What causes the glitch to be in one and not the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference you're hearing is because the Chrome team hasn't removed the dezippering that Chris Rogers originally put into the implementation.  Dezippering is a general process of smoothing parameter changes; e.g. instead of actually directly changing the value, you could call setTargetAtTime with a small t; then the value changes smoothly.

For delayTime, this is especially problematic, because any change may cause extreme glitches.  (Changes to a gain parameter, for example, MAY cause glitches, but they're likely to be a bit less dramatic.)

Chris' original implementation built dezippering in for all parameters, so that parameter changes would by default be smooth - in short, when you changed .value it wasn't really instantaneously changing the value.  However, this causes problems in some parameters (e.g. smoothing the frequency parameter on an oscillator creates a portamento-like effect, which is frequently undesirable).  Eventually, after much discussion (https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/76), the Web Audio Working Group decided that dezippering should not be automatic (you can, after all, always smooth parameters with setTargetAtTime); the Chromium team just needs to remove it from their code.  (Apparently Firefox hasn't removed their dezippering either.)

In your particular example, you're making an extreme change to delayTime - a four-second change - and it's getting "smoothed" across a very brief period of time.  This is akin to using an analog delay line, and very quickly changing the delayTime.  (Check out demos of the Korg Monotron Delay unit, and you'll hear sounds that sound familiar.  :)  By contrast, the instantaneous change (with setValueAtTime) is just "jumping" - it's probably causing a click, but you don't even hear it by comparison.

So, short story: don't use .value to set the delayTime in this instance, use setTargetAtTime() if you want it to be smoothed, or setValueAtTime() if you want it to be instantaneous.  Huge changes to a delayTime parameter, though, are always going to cause some kind of issue; you probably actually want to crossfade between two delay lines or something like that.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks for the clear explanation and for pointing me to the Korg Monotron Delay unit. That thing looks like loads of fun :) Cheers